# The fear of door knobs and being moved by the keeper

Tags: mansions-of-madness

There is an insanity card (one of my favorite as a keeper) that says that the investigator has to roll `will+2` everytime he/she walks through a door. What me and my players haven't been able to agree upon is whether the investigator should roll the dice even if it is the keeper who forces the player to move.

My gut says yes as in the same manner that you need to roll horror if the keeper moves you into a room with a monster as well. What is your opinion and are you able to find any basis for it in the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The investigator should roll even if they're forced through the door by the Keeper. It isn't covered explicitly in the rules, but it is essentially a horror test and the entire benefit of the trauma is that the Keeper should be able to exploit it.

I would say that, as with normal horror tests, passing through the same door more than once in the same turn should only force one test however.

Comment: Just to clarify, if a investigator had moved through a door at his turn (and rolled for it) then he shouldn't need to roll for it again if the keeper moves him again in the investigators turn or in the keepers turn? Anyhow, your answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I think the investigator should only roll once per door per turn. So for example the Keeper plays a Mythos card that forces him through the door in the Investigators turn and then if the Keeper moves him in the Keeper turn, he should roll roll again - That means the Keeper can mess with the Investigator a bit with Mythos and Keeper Actions but stops him from using the same action (most likely "Uncontrollable Urges") multiple times in his turn to keep forcing horror tests.